# How to run Selenium recorded test cases (instead of .java) with Maven?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc

I recorded with Selenium-IDE those are running perfectly, and exported as Java unit test cases. I try to run those Selenium Java Test cases. But I am getting lot of errors like 'Element not found', 'Element not visible'...., and I find that I have to learn so much to use it.

But my html test cases are working perfectly. So I got an idea to run html run cases instead of Java test cases. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can run Selenium IDE generated (HTML) test cases in maven.  I am currently doing this using the selenium-maven-plugin.  I ran into errors getting the plugin to launch firefox, so I point it to my chrome browser instead.

```
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <browser>*googlechrome C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe</browser>
        <suite>src/test/selenium/SeleniumTestSuite.html</suite>
        <startURL>http://localhost:7001/APP/jsp/index.faces/</startURL>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>run-selenium-tests</id>
            <phase>integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>selenese</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Also, your 'Element not found' problems may be occurring if your tests run too fast, and elements have not yet loaded.  If you are having this issue, the HTML tests can be slowed down by inserting setSpeed calls into each of the Test Cases HTML files.  This essentially does the same thing that the Fast-Slow slider (top left of Selenium IDE) does.

```
<tr>
<td>setSpeed</td>
<td>3000</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Straight from the [About Maven](http://maven.apache.org/what-is-maven.html) page...

> ...
>
> The result is a tool that can now be used for building and managing any Java-based project. We hope that we have created something that will make the day-to-day work of Java developers easier and generally help with the comprehension of any Java-based project.
>
> ...

Keyword here is any *Java-based* project, ergo - no.  it cannot run your recorded html tests.

The only alternative i can think of, is a plugin, but according to the [plugin page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/), there are no current available plugins for running selenium html tests.